# Visual Studio Strange Exception

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, winapi, cmake

I ported a project from Visual Studio Express (Windows SDK x64 with CMake) to Visual Studio 2010 Professional (Compiling for x64). Everything seems to work. I can compile the .dll projects that I transformed. Getting to my test projects I'm facing a strange behavior. (Link/Include libraries are set up the same way).

**Edit**
Same thing happens for *Release/Debug*.

**I get the following error** (when I rune the code in Visual Studio 2010):

```
 KernelBase.dll!RaiseException()  + 0x3d bytes  
 msvcr100.dll!_CxxThrowException()  + 0x81 bytes    
 000007fe8d54a043() 
 000007fe8d548700() 
 000007fe8d547d20() 
 000007fe8d547cee() 
 000007fe8d547c79() 
 clr.dll!000007feecbc822e()     
 [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for clr.dll]  
 kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk()  + 0xd bytes    
 ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()  + 0x21 bytes
```

Comment: You should provide MUCH more infos (when/where)

Comment: What information do you need? This is the stack I get from the error, besides that I don'get any other information from the compiler. I'm opened to suggestions.

Comment: which thread is that? do you start threads? How? Have you tried to debug step by step? Is there any C# involved? (clr.dll?)

Comment: Yes there are threads. I tried to debug but no solution yet. It's pure C/C++. I also looked for thread related issue but the code was running in the previous setup that's the strange.

Comment: So what is the clr.dll? Don't you have symbols for it? Try to identify which thread crash. You could OutputDebugString the TID at start.

Comment: Can you explain ho to do what you suggest? (The part what the symbols I check now.)

Comment: I just try to get some informations about the threads you launch and in which one is the crash. Did you also entirely rebuilded your test project with the new environement.

Comment: I still try to get info about the threads. Answer to you're questions is yes I rebuilt everything.

Comment: Are you able to debug "step-by-step", playing with the F10-F11 keys?

Comment: No I'm not able to do that.

Comment: When I want to go inside/stop at a break he goes further ...

Comment: Put a break point with F9. Wait the break. Use F10 or F11. if that don't work, your are in trouble

Comment: I did that already, what can be the problem?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41653/discussion-between-manuell-and-laszlo-andras-zsurzsa)

Comment: You need to set up Visual Studio to get debugging symbols to make anything out of the stack trace. See [Use the Microsoft Symbol Server to obtain debug symbol files](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503) and [Debugging with Symbols](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416588.aspx) for details.

Comment: Error found thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved thanks to the guys for helping me out with the debugging ...

So here's the deal:

I was creating multiple output windows. Every one of them were having a different thread. In the initialization part I had the following code:

```
  m_wndclassName = L"Output App"; // Here's the bug, the names should be different ...
  m_wndclass.style         = 0;
  m_wndclass.lpfnWndProc   = (WNDPROC)OpenGLSinkNode::wndProc;
  m_wndclass.cbClsExtra    = 0;
  m_wndclass.cbWndExtra    = 0;
  m_wndclass.hInstance     = NULL;
  m_wndclass.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, m_wndclassName.c_str());
  m_wndclass.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
  m_wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
  m_wndclass.lpszMenuName  = m_wndclassName.c_str();
  m_wndclass.lpszClassName = m_wndclassName.c_str();
```

Solution:

```
  m_wndclassName = L"Output App"; + std::to_wstring( (long double)m_id); // watch out here because std::to_wstring() has a bug ... you have to cast it to (long double), my_id of type int (Only in VS 2010, I read.)
```